# Parallel.Foreach issue

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a `Parallel.Foreach` loop that is giving me grief, and wanted to see if one of you guys could shed some light on this. Little to be found googling this unfortunately.

Here is the knot:

My foreach loop :

```
string [] Ids = {........}; //a string array of ID's
using(IUnitOfWork uw = GetUnitOfWork())
     {
            Parallel.ForEach(Ids, currentRecord =>
            {
                var x = (from h in uw.GetRepository<EFEntity1>().AsQueryable()
                         join k in uw.GetRepository<EFEntity2>().AsQueryable()
                         on h.ID equals k.ID
                         join l in uw.GetRepository<EFEntity3>().AsQueryable() on 
                          h.FundAccount equals l.FundAccount
                         where h.ID == currentRecord
                         select new { h.x, h.y, h.z});
                foreach (var v in x)
                {
                    if (v.SomeMember == "foo")
                    {

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Output : {0} {1} {2} {3} {4} ", v.x, 
                                      v.y, v.z);
                }
            });
        }
```

The LINQ statement is where I get an `ArgumentExcpetion` thrown saying:

> *An item with the same key has already been added*

Any clues to what might be wrong with my implemntation of the foreach loop in this scenario?

Appreciate the support.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're pushing everything into the same `Ids` string array.

Comment: My first thought here - Entity Framework's `DbContext` is not thread safe, so *probably* by extension your `UnitOfWork` is not either. Move the `using` inside the parallel loop, so each parallel iteration gets its own context.

Comment: Is it exactly the same code whose throws the exception?

Comment: Your UnitOfWork is not thread-safe.

Comment: Try to put your UnitOfWork to a thread-safe array list prior you query.

Comment: Hmmm...some good thought there gentlemen, thanks. Let me follow up on your answers here. Much appreciated, thankls

Comment: @Trust me - I'm a Doctor : That was the ticket. The thread safety issue with UnitOfWork was what broke the parallel foreach. In the back of my mind I knew that EF DBContext was not thread safe so yes in extension UnitOfWork was not either. Moving the using inside the parallel loop was necessary.Staring at it for an hour I lost focus. You guys brought me back to to sanity :-) Thanks and Happy Coding ! Anders

Comment: could you please write your solution as answer to your own question

Comment: I second @SACO, this one needs a formal answer.  Please post the working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this with moving the using bracket into the Parellel loop. Reason was because the dbcontext is not thread-safe.